# Identity server 4 - PasswordSignInAsync method throws IsNotAllowed=true

Tags: azure, .net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 for user management and hosted application in Azure. Once I created user, try to sign in using below method:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false,  false);
```

Its working fine when I'm tested locally(visual studio 2017). 
But its not working  properly after hosted to Azure.

Frequently it throws the error

> Not Allowed("Authentication failed for username: "te***@***.com", reason: not allowed").

I entered correct username and password.

So whenever received that error, I restart the AppService(Azure). After restarting, It works fine for sometime. So again and again I'm facing same problem.

Anyone please clarify why this error occurred and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PasswordSignInAsync will return 'Not Allowed' if ...

1. The current user email address is not yet verified
2. The identity system is configured to 'require email verification'

You have two options ...

1. Disable 'require email verification' or ...
2. Do not sign in the user until email has been verified (ie redirect to a page asking them to check their email and verify their email address)

Hope this is understandable.